# Wordpress not full image in prettyphoto

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I do have problem with gallery in my wordpress page.
I did upload image with 1920x1080 resolution but when the image popup on the page and when i click the fullscreen icon the image has only 1024x560 and also right now i don't see full screen button.
Here is the site: [my site](http://formacjaprojekt.pl/portfolio-posts/dom-jednorodzinny-karwiany-k-wroclawia/)

Comment: This is because wordpress sets default image sizes. You could try to increase the size in the functions.php or check if there are any settings for the plugin

Comment: I can't find anything like that

Comment: In your backend goto Settings->Media increase the size of the Large image to 1920x1080. Be aware you need to regenerate the images, they don't just automatically get resized

Comment: So after that change in setting i need to upload these images again?

Comment: OK it worked i changed the setteings and uploaded again images, but i need to  get back fulklscreen button because right now it's 1920 and i don't see it very good on my 1366 resolution

Comment: Great glad i could help ;)